# if i set a value with js and use prevent default, the value isnt there in c#

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

i have some html buttons that set a value in a asp textbox.  to prevent the slow response of each button click and to stop the constant refresh of the page, i use e.preventDefault()

if i do this, when i then click an asp:button that calls a c# method, the value (that i can visually see) is not returned in the c# method

I origianlly didnt use e.preventDefault but the button response was slow and constantly executed page_load, using the preventdefault made it nice and repsonse

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="itemScanned" type="text" ClientIDMode="Static"
                        autocomplete="false" onfocus="setfocus('itemScanned')" ReadOnly="true"
                        Style="width: 195px; height: 27px" />

<script type="text/javascript">
                function numclick(x, e) {
                    var w;
                    if (document.getElementById('item_or_quantity_focus').value == "itemScanned") {
                        w = document.getElementById('itemScanned');
                    } else {
                        w = document.getElementById('Quantity');
                    }

                    if (x > -1) {
                        w.value += x;

                    } else {
                        if (x == -1) {
                            if (w.value.length > 0) w.value = w.value.substring(0, w.value.length - 1);
                        }
                        if (x == -2 && w == "itemScanned") {
                            document.getElementById('<%=BtnRead.ClientID %>').click();
                        }
                        if (x == -2 && w == "Quantity") {
                            document.getElementById('<%=BtnCommit.ClientID %>').click();
                        }
                    }


                    e.preventDefault();

                }


<asp:Button runat="server" ID="BtnRead" Text="Read" OnClick="BtnRead_click"
                        class="btn btn-primary"
                        Style="height: 30px; width: 80px; padding: 0px; font-size: 14px; margin: 0px" />
```

i have a collection of number buttons, they call the function and the itemscanned field is populated as each button is pressed
i then click the read button which calls the c# method
the itemscanned.Text is ""

how can i refresh the page from C# when i click read to ensure i have the values

Comment: `e.preventDefault()` method makes sure that whatever you are trying to send from the client to server does not happen. Simply removing this should solve your problem. If you are having long loading times, consider an approach to shorten these times such as seperating your data over different screens or pages, controls and maybe make use of filters. You are probably trying to save a big amount of data on a single click.

Comment: so, it turns out... that, if you set read only on a textbox in the asp tag on html, is not readable, But, if i set the attribute of the textbox for read only from code then it is.
this works perfectly.  hope that helps someone else.
the prevent default is needed as the buttons are number entry ones that need to be ultra responsive.